# Can't delete a mySQL table. (Error 1050)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1050

I have a pesky table that will not delete and it's holding up my dev environment refresh :(

I know this table exists. Example...

```
mysql> select * from uc_order_products_qty_vw limit 10;
+-----+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| nid | order_count | avg_qty | sum_qty | max_qty | min_qty |
+-----+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 105 |           1 |  1.0000 |       1 |       1 |       1 | 
| 110 |           5 |  1.0000 |       5 |       1 |       1 | 
| 111 |           1 |  1.0000 |       1 |       1 |       1 | 
| 113 |           5 |  1.0000 |       5 |       1 |       1 | 
| 114 |           1 |  1.0000 |       1 |       1 |       1 | 
| 115 |           1 |  1.0000 |       1 |       1 |       1 | 
| 117 |           2 |  1.0000 |       2 |       1 |       1 | 
| 119 |           3 |  1.3333 |       4 |       2 |       1 | 
| 190 |           5 |  1.0000 |       5 |       1 |       1 | 
| 199 |           2 |  1.0000 |       2 |       1 |       1 | 
+-----+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However when I try to drop it...

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uc_order_products_qty_vw;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

It doesn't work, the table is still there, and the warning says this...

```
mysql> show warnings limit 1;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                  |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1051 | Unknown table 'uc_order_products_qty_vw' | 
+-------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Feeling pretty dumbfounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the name it might be a view. Try using [DROP VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-view.html):

```
DROP VIEW uc_order_products_qty_vw
```

[DROP TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html) doesn't work for views:

```
CREATE VIEW test_vw AS SELECT 1;
SELECT * FROM test_vw;    -- works
DROP TABLE test_vw;       -- error: Unknown table 'test_vw'
DROP VIEW test_vw;        -- works
```

Comment: Yeah, the `vw` at the end seems to be a dead giveaway that this is a _view_ rather than a table.

Comment: Wonder if there is a parameter I can pass in my mysqldump that will make the incorrect "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" statements into "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS" ?